# List Storage Accounts only listing a few classic storage accounts

Tags: rest, azure

List Storage Accounts https://management.core.windows.net//services/storageservices

says that it lists the storage accounts that are available in the specified subscription and the get storage account keys work only for these storage accounts that are returned as part of this call.

But the response is giving me only few storage accounts which are classic, how do i get the other storage accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response,by other storage accounts I meant the storage accounts under the classic storage accounts itself which were not getting listed.
Instead of using 
 https://management.core.windows.net//services/storageservices

I used the REST API's 
for the new storage accounts
/management.azure.com/subscriptions/id/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2016-12-01

for classic:
/management.azure.com/subscriptions//providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts?api-version=

and to get keys
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/listKeys?api-version=2016-12-01

/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/listKeys?api-version=2016-11-01

Answer (score 0):

> But the response is giving me only few storage accounts which are
>   classic, how do i get the other storage accounts?

By `"other"` storage accounts, I guess you're meaning `"Azure Resource Manager (ARM)"` storage accounts. There's a different API to get ARM storage accounts that make use of Azure AD based authentication.

To learn more about ARM API to list storage accounts, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts#StorageAccounts_List.

To learn more about how to authenticate/authorize ARM API calls, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gaurav Mantri, if you’d like to list ARM storage accounts under a specified subscription, please use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts#StorageAccounts_List):

> GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2016-12-01

And the following code sample works fine on my side, please refer to it.

```
string tenantId = "{tenantId}";
string clientId = "{clientId}";
string clientSecret = "{secret}";
string subscriptionid = "{subscriptionid}";

string authContextURL = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId;
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential: credential);

if (result == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
}

string token = result.AccessToken;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2016-12-01", subscriptionid));

request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers["Authorization"] =  "Bearer " + token;  


HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    //extract data from response
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    //ex.Message;
}
```

Besides, this article explained how to [create AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application), please refer to it.